# Radio Button Check code useless

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, vb.net-2010

I get text from database in a textbox, then with that text what I'm trying to do is selecting the particular Radio Button checked.

I tried many methods to achieve the goal, but didn't reached to the solution yet.

```
If Edt_Premium_Payment.Text = "YLY" Then
    Edt_RB_YLY.Checked = True        
ElseIf Edt_Premium_Payment.Text = "HLY" Then
    Edt_RB_HLY.Checked = True
ElseIf Edt_Premium_Payment.Text = "QLY" Then
    Edt_RB_QLY.Checked = True
ElseIf Edt_Premium_Payment.Text = "MLY" Then
    Edt_RB_MLY.Checked = True
End If
```

**Edited:-**
Sorry I forgot about the debugger.
The following four radio buttons still seem unselected(Unchecked).
I mean their .Checked property looks false.

**Edited2:-**
Actually **Edt_Premium_Payment** is the textbox in which I get value(database text).
Then I compare the text with the **Radio Buttons**.
When the text match with any **Radio Button** That **Radio Button** would be shown as checked.
Let say that the **Edt_Premium_Payment** text gets matched with **Edt_RB_YLY** which is a **Radio Button**. After then this **Radio Button** should be shown as checked.
But with me it show the particular **Radio Button** unchecked.
A PerformClick() simply mark checked the **Radio Button**, so this is what I want.

I can't upload picture so assume this as the picture, I hope it'd be enough to get understand.

```
1) ( )YLY  
2) ( )HLY  
3) ( )QLY  
4) ( )MLY
```

Now the Edt_Premium_Payment.text contains the text "YLY".  So I should get output as:

```
1) (.)YLY  
2) ( )HLY  
3) ( )QLY  
4) ( )MLY
```

Instead of this output I get the output same as all are unchecked. As:

```
1) ( )YLY  
2) ( )HLY  
3) ( )QLY  
4) ( )MLY
```

**Edited 3**
Maybe this would help you guys to understand my question.
The following Code is unresponsive. No conflict, No error just unresponsive.

```
Private Sub Go_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Go.Click

Select Case dr.Item("Premium_Payment_Mode").ToString
                Case "HLY"
                    Edt_RB_HLY.Checked = True
                Case "MLY"
                    Edt_RB_MLY.Checked = True
                Case "QLY"
                    Edt_RB_QLY.Checked = True
                Case "YLY"
                    Edt_RB_YLY.Checked = True
                Case Else
                    Edt_Premium_Payment.Text = dr.Item("Premium_Payment_Mode")
            End Select

End Sub
```

I also tried new project containg 3 radio buttons, 1 textbox and a button. Details are:
**Radio Buttons Texts Are:** YLY, QLY and MLY.
**Radio Buttons Names Are respectively:** YL, QL and ML.
**Textbox name is:** a

Now the code which I tried is

```
Public Class Form1

Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    If a.Text = YL.Text Then
        YL.Checked = True
    ElseIf a.Text = ML.Text Then
        ML.Checked = True
    ElseIf a.Text = QL.Text Then
        QL.Checked = True

    End If
End Sub
End Class
```

In VB 2013 the radio button has checkstate but it is not available in vb 2010.
I want to change the checkstate from 0 to 1 through code.
Guyz Please it's more than enough to understand my question now, F1.
F1.
F1.

Comment: What is the debugger doing while you step through this code line by line?

Comment: See the Edited part in the question, and thnx LarsTech for reminding.

Comment: Maybe you need to show us what you are doing in that click event of the radiobuttons.

Comment: Don't call `PerformClick();`

Comment: I tried it without the PerformClick() event with RadioButton.Clicked = true only, still it's not working.

Comment: Where are you calling this code and what is the value of `Me.Edt_Premium_Payment.Text` when you do?

Comment: Me.Edt_Premium_Payment.Text is the text box which i am comparing with radio button. and i am call it to **Edt_Premium_Payment.TextChanged** event.

Comment: I also used this condition in the button by which I'm fetching data from database.

Comment: The code you posted does not reproduce the issue you are describing.

Comment: What does the code now says? I just want you to clear me that why radio button deos not get active(to checked = true) with this conditional code which i wrote on the button.

Comment: Three possibilities: 1) your textbox does not have any of those values 2) you don't have the event actually handled, or 3) you have some other event code that interferes with this.

Comment: Thnx LarsTech, but I think you are thinking only through C# posibilities and it's VB, VB programmers can simply understand and give their solution. or may be you having other troubble.

Comment: I work in both languages.  Your code works as posted.  If it doesn't, then you don't have the text string matching correctly.  Maybe it's lowercase.  Maybe you have extra spaces.  `may be you having other troubble` — not sure why you think this is my problem.

Comment: Please don't take my words wrong. I didn't meant to hurt you.  There are hundreds of people here who didn't gave solution to me. LarsTech you and Basic tried.  Thnx, It seems that I have to re-install Windows. Because I can't see any problem or other solution which i could get on.

Comment: Reinstalling windows is not the solution.  Try working on a simple new project where you have radio buttons and get them to be checked true through your code.  Start simple to get it working, then add the needed complexity as you go.

Comment: It is working on a button lonely but it does not work along with.
    Textbox1.text = dr.Item("choice")
    If TextBox1.Text = "Q" Then
            RadioButton1.Checked = True
        ElseIf TextBox1.Text = "W" Then
            RadioButton2.Checked = True
        ElseIf TextBox1.Text = "e" Then
            RadioButton3.Checked = True
        ElseIf
            RadioButton4.Checked = True
        End If

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean you want something like this... ?

```
Select Case Edt_Premium_Payment.Text
    Case "YLY"
        Edt_RB_YLY.Checked = True 
    Case "MLY"
        Edt_RB_MLY.Checked = True 
    ....
End Select
```

The `Select` statement will run the first branch that is equal,

Note that if you're having trouble selecting a radio button, you need to develop your skills a lot before you should consider doing anything payment-related. (A guess from the control name `Edt_Premium_Payment`). It's a very advanced topic and easy to get wrong.

Comment: Thanks Basic by going towards a solution beyond questioning my question.  I tried the select case also it didn't worked. the radio button is still unchecked.  And the Payment is just my own work.  I'm really stucked here.